# cannot find adminpack.sql in postgresql 9.1

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to get it installed and use in ubuntu. Was following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) page to install the additional instrumentation packages.

```
Install Server Instrumentation for Postgresql 8.4
To install Server Instrumentation for Postgresql 8.4 you may use the command line and type:
 sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib

Run the adminpack.sql script, simply type:
 sudo -u postgres psql < /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/adminpack.sql
```

But I couldn't find adminpack.sql in 9.1 version.

Comment: Mirror question in AskUbuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/184577/postgresql-9-1-adminpack-install

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `locate adminpack`. But first, run `updatedb` to make sure the `locate` database is up to date.

```
sudo updatedb
locate adminpack
```

The output is:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/adminpack.so
/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/adminpack--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/adminpack.control
```

Comment: locate doesn't find any file.

Comment: Did you see in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/extension`?

Comment: there are only 2 folders within 9.1 folder - bin and lib

Comment: Try `pkg -L postgresql-contrib-9.1` and you will see, what files are installed and where.

Comment: If upon `sudo updatedb` you get `updatedb: command not found`, [install `locate` first](http://serverfault.com/a/196507/58481)

Answer (score 24):

In PostgreSQL 9.1 and later, extensions can be installed via the `CREATE EXTENSION` command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
CREATE EXTENSION "adminpack";
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is old and comments are closed, so I'm opening another answer.

ldalonzo's answer is correct once you have all the components, but I found I also had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1
```

Looks like the bare postgresql package doesn't include the additional modules.

Answer (score 2):

Once you install postgresql-contrib using below command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

Adminpack is located in the below path

```
/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/adminpack--1.0.sql
```

To load the adminpack use the below command

```
sudo su postgres -c psql < /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/adminpack--1.0.sql
```

Then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```